# Rails primary key and object id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm accessing a rails model with the typical primary key `id`.  However, when I access it in a method, I get the following warning.

```
Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id
```

It seems it's getting confused between object id, and the primary key for the model.  is there a way to make sure its using the field `id`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like the object you've called `.id` on is not actually an ActiveRecord model. You should only see that warning for Ruby objects where `.id` is the soon-to-be deprecated version of `Object#object_id`.

However, another way to access the primary key for the field with an ActiveRecord model is `model.attributes['id']` so you could try that.

Answer (score 2):

As mikej points out, you called `id` on a non-Active-Record. To verify, [check out the object's class by using `obj.class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000350).

Please note, though, with duck-typing class doesn't matter... unless you think the object is a different class than it is :)