# Rails: Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, deprecated

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails primary key and object id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173811/rails-primary-key-and-object-id)

Very quick question. My server is warning me that line 37 will be deprecated, specifically:

```
#Server error:
views/projects/index.html.erb:37: warning: Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id

#Views/projects/index.html.erb:
6: <% for project in @projects do %>
36: <%= project.id %>
37: <%= Matching.find_all_by_customer_id_and_project_id( @customer.id, project.id).id %>
38: <%= @customer.id %>
```

Here's my confusion. Line 36 project.id isn't raising a warning, so I assume the issue is that I'm calling ID on the Matching model. Why is it the case that only Matching raising an error and not customer or project? How can I rectify this in my code?

Thanks very  much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either `@customer` or your `Matching` object is probably nil. `nil.id` is a deprecated method referring to nil's object ID.

Check that both `@customer` and the `Matching` object you get contain something before going ahead with this part of the template, and you should be fine.