# Why getting error: Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, object, heroku

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails primary key and object id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173811/rails-primary-key-and-object-id)

On my local development rails environment, I am able to check the output from a SOAP call just fine.

I can use `response.id` to get the value from this packet displayed using the .inspect method:

```
#<SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x15702d0c0604 {}id="dd26ce5f-0cfd-9bbb-3485-4c64c9d6378
4" {}error=#<SOAP::Mapping::Object:0x15702d0bf6f0 {}number="0" {}name="No Error"
 {}description="No Error">>
```

HOWEVER, when I push it up to heroku, I get this error:

```
/disk1/home/slugs/212074_6b040a6_5c2e/mnt/app/controllers/sugarcrm_controller.rb
:77: warning: Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id
```

Driving me crazy to understand the discrepancy.

Suggestions?

Comment: Did you check all your needed gems are available?

Comment: How do I do that?  I don't get any errors regarding the gems...there are some require statements in the gem that does all the SOAP stuff connecting to the SugarCRM API...but I assumed those were existing libraries?

Comment: dupplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173811/rails-primary-key-and-object-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may have a bug in your code, which is why that warning is thrown. `Object#id` is most often invoked when you are inadvertently calling `id` on an object you weren't expecting, like `nil`:

```
>> nil.id
(irb):1: warning: Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id
 => 4
```

If the object has an `id` method, a warning is not thrown. So, assuming it works locally (and this SOAP object does have an `id` method), the only way you should be getting this warning is if it is a different kind of object.

Thus, are you absolutely sure the object you expected is being returned? Try adding:

```
logger.info ">>> SOAP OBJECT: " + object.inspect
```

Or add some explicit error handling / object checking:

```
unless object.is_a?(SOAP::Mapping::Object)
  raise ArgumentError, "did not get SOAP object"
end
```

At least then you will know something has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably used to ActiveRecord based objects and this object doesn't look like it's based off of ActiveRecord. `id` is [soon to be deprecated](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000348), and [`object_id`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000339) is a method on a Ruby object.

This doesn't mean that `id` on ActiveRecord is going to be deprecated, just on "plain old Ruby  objects".

Comment: Because I write like I talk. I am a hideous American.