# Why "Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id" when accessing AR record ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails primary key and object id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173811/rails-primary-key-and-object-id)

I am baffled as to why I cannot refer an object's attributes; hope someone can help...

I need to build a hash that will associate Marker.marker_name with it's id from the database, which are already stored (the record id will serve as a foreign key in another table).

So, first I retrieve the Marker record via this named scope:

```
class Marker < ActiveRecord::Base    
named_scope :by_name, lambda { |marker_name| 
    {:conditions => ["marker_name = ?", marker_name]}}
```

which is called from my Uploads model, like this (marker_name has the value "Amelogenin"):

```
this_marker = Marker.by_name(marker_name)
```

I know this worked, because when I Use the debugger, I can see what is in this_marker, which looks like:

> ### (rdb:2) y this_marker
>
> - !ruby/object:Marker   attributes:
>     created_at: 2011-03-14 22:21:27.244885
>     updated_at: 2011-03-14 22:21:27.244885
>     id: "11"
>     marker_name: Amelogenin   attributes_cache: {}

Yet, I cannot assign the record id in my hash, like this:

```
$markers[marker_name] = this_marker.id
```

I cannot seem to refer directly to the id in this way; because, even in the debugger, I get this error:

```
(rdb:2) p this_marker.id
(__DELEGATION__):2: warning: Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id
```

Is there some kind of different Ruby syntax I need to be using or what? How can I associate the marker_name with its record id?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: dupplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173811/rails-primary-key-and-object-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `Marker.by_name(marker_name)` returns an `array` of makers. You should write:

```
this_marker = Marker.by_name(marker_name).first
```

Comment: Thanks Voldy! This answer seemed best...

Answer (score 0):

That *is* a very confusing error message, (and I bet it's a fairly common problem too).

`Marker.by_name(marker_name)` does not return an active record object, but a scope, which does not have an active record id, only the `Object#id` method, which is deprecated (and gone in Ruby 1.9.2).

Scopes are lazy - they won't access the database until you try to use them (or print them, as in your case).

Try `Marker.by_name(marker_name).first`

Comment: Ok, tried that, no luck; same problem, returns the same thing. But you're right, it does return a scope. How do I get the actual record, so I get the record id? thx...

Comment: Hmmm, that's surprising, even if it's an older version of Rails. What version is it? Anyway, start up `ruby script/console` and try out a few things: `scope = Marker.by_name("Amelogenin"); scope.class; scope.all.class; scope.to_a.class; scope.to_a.first.class`. One of these should be your AR object, and if not, please tell what they are instead.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error happens when one calls `id` method on non ActiveRecord object. So make sure `this_marker` is AR object instance.

`this_marker = Marker.by_name(marker_name)` are you sure this returns one Marker object? There is no call to `all` or `first`.