# Object#id will be deprecated warning when accessing ActiveRecord ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails primary key and object id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173811/rails-primary-key-and-object-id)

I have the following code in my `Event` model

```
  def event_tokens=(ids)
    events = ids.split(',')
    allowed_events = []
    events.each do |i|
      i = i.strip
      event = Event.where("upper(name) = ?", i.upcase);
      if event.present?
        allowed_events << event.id #line w/ error
      else
        print "this doesnt exist, add in staging table " + i.to_s
      end
    end
    self.event_ids = allowed_events
  end
```

the `event.id` in the above code is throwing a warning

> warning: Object#id will be
>   deprecated; use Object#object_id

when I changed `event.id` to `event[:id]` I'm getting an error

> Symbol as array index

Comment: dupplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173811/rails-primary-key-and-object-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
event = Event.where("upper(name) = ?", i.upcase);
```

... returns a collection (well, technically, a proxy to a collection), not an ActiveRecord object.

Try:

```
events = Event.where("upper(name) = ?", i.upcase)
event = (events.blank? ? nil : events.first)
```